# Separate values by comma and Joins Table in LINQ

Tags: c#, webapi

Below is my C# API response to get the Data. In the SymptomsId field, I will have values separated by Comma (1,2,3). I need to separate the values by comma and need to get the Description of it from the Symptoms Master table. I need to get all the descriptions for the values mentioned in the SymptomsID field and return it in the List.

```
 public Response<List<ProductDiseaseModelDescResponse>> getProductDisease(string farmId,int languageId)
            {
                var response = new Response<List<ProductDiseaseModelDescResponse>>();
    
                try
                {
                    //var productDiseaseList = context.productDisease.Where(x => x.FarmId == farmId).OrderByDescending(x=> x.DiseaseId).ToList();
                    var productDiseaseList = (
                                from pd in context.productDisease
                                join practice in context.practice on pd.PracticeId equals practice.PracticeId
                                join productGroup in context.productGroup on pd.ProductGroupId equals productGroup.ProductGroupId
                                where pd.FarmId == farmId && practice.LanguagueId == languageId && productGroup.LanguageId == languageId
                                orderby pd.DiseaseId descending
                                select new ProductDiseaseModelDescResponse
                                {
                                    DiseaseId = pd.DiseaseId,
                                    IncidentName = pd.IncidentName,
                                    IncidentDate = pd.IncidentDate,
                                    FarmId = pd.FarmId,
                                    BatchId = pd.BatchId,
                                    ProductGroupId = pd.ProductGroupId,
                                    ProductGroupDesc = productGroup.ProductGroupDescription,
                                    PracticeId = pd.PracticeId,
                                    PracticeDesc = practice.PracticeDescription,
                                    ReportedBy = pd.ReportedBy,
                                    ProductId = pd.ProductId,
                                    DiseaseDescription = pd.DiseaseDescription,
                                    DiseaseIdentificationDate = pd.DiseaseIdentificationDate,
                                    SymptomsId = pd.SymptomsId,
                                    SymptomsDesc = pd.SymptomsId.Split(',')
                                                 .Select(symptomId =>
                                                     context.productSymptoms
                                                            .Where(ps => ps.SymptomId.ToString() == symptomId && ps.LanguageId == languageId)
                                                            .Select(ps => ps.SymptomDescription)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault())
                                                 .ToList(),
                                    IsIsolated = pd.IsIsolated,
                                    IsHomeTreatmentTried = pd.IsHomeTreatmentTried,
                                    SpecialistId = pd.SpecialistId,
                                    SpecialistRecomandationFollowed = pd.SpecialistRecomandationFollowed,
                                    TicketClosed = pd.TicketClosed,
                                    TicketClosedDate = pd.TicketClosedDate,
                                    HomeRemedyDetail = pd.HomeRemedyDetail,
                                    Image1 = pd.Image1,
                                    Image2 = pd.Image2,
                                    Image3 = pd.Image3,
                                    Image4 = pd.Image4,
                                    CreatedBy = pd.CreatedBy,
                                    IsSpecialistAddressed = pd.IsSpecialistAddressed,
                                    IsDiseaseSent = pd.IsDiseaseSent,
                                }
                            ).ToList();
    
                    if (productDiseaseList.Any())
                    {
                        response.Result = productDiseaseList;
                        response.ErrorCode = ResponseStatus.Success;
                        response.ErrorMessage = ResponseMessages.Success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.ErrorCode = ResponseStatus.Failure;
                        response.ErrorMessage = ResponseMessages.NoData;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    response.ErrorCode = ResponseStatus.Error;
                    response.ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
                }
    
                return response;
    
            }
```

Comment: I don't think EF can translate that into SQL. What you can do is here (If you insist on using EF) create a table-valued function that accepts a string and returns the related SymptomsDescs at SQL level. Define a custom function for EF and call it in above query